# Android, не открывает активти

Tags: android, activity, android-layout

Проблема решена! Извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, проблема решена. Ошибка была в том, что нельзя было передать объект, попробовал как в совете и все хорошо.  Спасибо за помощь!

---

Такая проблема. Есть у нас список, при клике мы открываем детальную информацию о нем. Вот код открытие новой активности:

```
 Log.e("samuliak", "Find obj!" + name.getText());
                intent.putExtra("OBJ", list.get(i));
                Log.e("samuliak", "Push obj!");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Log.e("samuliak", "Intent start!");
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                Log.e("samuliak", "activity start!");
                break;
```

По логам видно, что оно находит и запускает, но появляется белый экран и крашится. Вот код активности, на которую переходим:

```
package com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.Model.LeaderModel;
import com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.R;

public class DetailLeaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("samuliak", "super constructor");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_leader);
        Log.e("samuliak", "layout is ok");
        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leaderNameDetail);
        TextView tvPosition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leaderPositionDetail);
        TextView tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailInfo);
        ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.leaderPhoto);
        LeaderModel leader = (LeaderModel) getIntent().getExtras().get("OBJ");
        Log.e("samuliak", "OBJ is ok!");
        assert leader != null;
        assert tvInfo != null;
        assert tvName != null;
        assert tvPosition != null;
        assert photo != null;
        photo.setImageBitmap(leader.getPhoto());
        tvName.setText(leader.getName());
        tvPosition.setText(leader.getPosition());
        tvInfo.setText(leader.getdDetailInfo());
        Log.e("samuliak", "All good");
    }

}
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ListAllLeadershipActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_leadership"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.DetailLeaderActivity"/>
        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.HistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_suka"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ReplacementActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_replacement"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.NewsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_news"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.DetailNews" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.MapActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Логи:

```
05-10 02:11:17.865 788-805/system_process A/ActivityManager: Exception thrown launching activities in ProcessRecord{2acf2acb 31081:com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta/u0a66}
                                                             android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                                                                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                                                                 at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:797)
                                                                 at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1181)
                                                                 at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:551)
                                                                 at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6021)
                                                                 at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:6083)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:480)
                                                                 at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2208)
                                                                 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Comment: Скиньте сюда Ваши логи креша, а то экстрасенсы еще не проснулись

Comment: сейчас прикреплю. Уже есть

Comment: Что хранится в ```list``` и покажите как создаете сам ```Intent```?

Comment: Обычно ответ, который Вам помог, стоит помечать зеленой галочкой ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код

```
photo.setImageBitmap(leader.getPhoto());
```

А так же то, что Вы через интент передаете объект `LeaderModel`, подводит меня к мысли, что в этом генерик класе у Вас хранится `Bitmap`

```
 android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
```

Говорит о том, что вы в делаете то что я описал выше.

Не передавайте `Bitmap` через Intent, сохраните картинку в кеше и передавайте ссылку на него (`String`).

Либо Используйте библиотеки, которые сделают все это за Вас. К примеру при нужной настройки `UniversalImageLoader` будет за вас ее грузить и кешировать. Вам достаточно только хранить ссылку из интернета, библиотека сама поймет, брать ее из кеша с телефона или качать из интернета